# Outlook quick-steps functionality on Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, mail-rules

In Outlook 2010 on Windows, I use the quick steps functionality a lot to automatically sort incoming messages to different folders. The good thing is it applies these rules on subsequent messages as well. For example - if I don't want to be part of a conversation, I create a rule called "Mute" which will move that message to a folder called "Muted" and Mark as Read. All future messages with the same subject line automatically get moved to the Muted folder. I have several such folders like Follow-up, Hold, Archive etc. All new messages automatically flow to those folders. It helps me keep everything organized.

I had to move to using a Mac and I'm sorely missing this feature in Outlook 2011 for Mac. Is there ANY app out there (free or paid) that mimics the quick-step feature on Mac with support for Exchange?

Comment: @sorin Thanks for the edit. We'll use [tag:office-365] for the 2015 outlook and [tag:ms-office] for the rest. See the [chat room for tag usage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2510/better-tags-for-ask-different) and/or [meta] if you'd like to fine tune this.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Outlook, the 2011 outlook is a lousy rewrite of Entourage and 2015 Outlook X is just a new UI looking like 2013.

If you want similar functionality you need to use Apple Mail and plug-ins like MailHub. Please know that Mailhub is a for pay plug-in, but you can test drive it. Personally I have completely given up on Microsoft at this point in time as there are so many missing functions in their Outlook, from accepting a proposed time change in calendar, no ability for Quick-Step, even worse no rule (they track the reply and link it, so you might figure I can pick that up and write rule that moves e-mails after reply as an example) NO not Microsoft.

As I said Mailhub and a couple of plug-ins make life better.